# Expanding Brackets in Financial Appraisal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wondered if anyone could offer some help regarding how certain values were obtained in an expression with expanded brackets?

More particularly, I'd like to know the steps in obtaining the value '50' in denominator the below final expression, and more importantly if someone could provide a general road-map for when dealing with expanding out similar brackets.

The expression is given:

(1+ r/100)^2 = (1+ r/100)(1+ r/100) = 1+ r/50 + r^2/10000

And subsequently it would be appreciated if someone could explain how the values '400r' '2r^2' and '80r' are obtained when the above expression is plugged into:

20,000(1+ r/100)^2 = 8000 (1+ r/100)^2 +15000

--->>>> 20,000 + 400r + 2r^2 = 8000 + 80r +15000

Your help on the matter would be appreciated.

Best,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

For the first expression use (or remember, or work out with the distributive law) the fact that
$$
(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 .
$$
In your question $a=1$ and $b = r/100$. The $50$ in the denominator comes from
$$
2ab = \frac{2r}{100} = \frac{r}{50}.
$$

What follows "and subsequently" is wrong (which you can tell by seeing what it says when $r=0$).